# How can I show the menu options once my function is executed?

Tags: shell, scripting, menu

I have the below script:

```
while true; do
  echo "# Available tests:"
  PS3="Please select which test must be performed [1-9]: "
  options=("CPU Stress Test (local)" "Memory Stress Test (local)" "Intensive Random Write I/O on disks (5 min) (local)" "Intensive Random Read I/O on disks (5 min) (local)" "Intensive Read I/O on disks (5 min) (local)" "Intensive Write on disks I/O (5 min) (local)" "Cache Read Capability (local)" "Measure Network Bandwidth (Between nodes)" "Quit")
  select opt in "${options[@]}"
  do
    case $opt in
    "CPU Stress Test (local)")
            sleep 2
            cpu
            cleanup
    ;;
    "Memory Stress Test (local)")
            sleep 2
            memory
            cleanup
    ;;
    "Intensive Random Write I/O on disks (5 min) (local)")
            prereq
            cslist
            randwrite
            sleep 2
    ;;
    "Intensive Random Read I/O on disks (5 min) (local)")
            sleep 2
    ;;
    "Intensive Read I/O on disks (5 min) (local)")
            sleep 2
    ;;
    "Intensive Write on disks I/O (5 min) (local)")
            sleep 2
    ;;
    "Cache Read Capability (local)")
            sleep 2
    ;;
    "Measure Network Bandwidth (Between nodes)")
            sleep 2
    ;;
    "Quit")
            echo "All right, bye bye! :)"
            echo "Exiting..."
            sleep 2
            exit 1
    ;;
    *) echo "Invalid option ($REPLY)";;
    esac
  done
done
```

If I choose option 1 `CPU Stress Test (local)` for example, it is being executed successfully but at the end appear only my `PS3` question without the options from `select opt in...`, can anyone please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [`select` construct won't quit until a `break` command is executed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html).

So after each action is completed, use the `break` command:

```bsh
    case $opt in
    "CPU Stress Test (local)")
            sleep 2
            cpu
            cleanup
            break
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you @schrodigerscatcuriosity !!